# Ruby on Rails, css background image tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am using the Ruby on Rails Asset Pipeline. [I am using the image tag in css exactly how the documentation shows.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) I am not interested in using any other tag, I want this one to work. Why isn't `image-url` rewriting the name of `background.jpg` to `background-d9fabe43d680f19426ae7003799ad43a.jpg`?

My css file has the `.scss` extension as the precompiler requires.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: image-url("background.jpg");
}
```

JavaScript console error:

```
GET https://mywebsite.com/assets/background.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Are you deploying to heroku, and if so, have you added the rails12factor gem? `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

Comment: Please do not downvote - this is a legitimate issue that is not well documented on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Marcus - Yes, I do have that gem included.

Comment: Sambhav - the documentation says that the unique fingerprint will be added to the url, but as I have shown, it was not. Therefore, it is not working exactly as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the below code to `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( .jpg )
```

Comment: I do not know why people are downvoting, but this is the solution. The fingerprint is not being added to the url as shown in the documentation.